# Compass will not create or compile in new Ruby version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I have been using Compass for a bit now, and just recently changed the environment on my mac to begin the [Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321743121). After installing Ruby 1.9.3, and re-updating my Ruby Gems, I installed Compass once again. Now whenever I try to do any command with compass (create, watch, etc) it gives me the same error:

```
You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
```

I'm completely clueless. Thanks so much for any pointers.

Edit: After further exploration, it seems it isn't reading any Compass commands. I can literally try

```
compass whateverdude
```

and receive the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.3, sass-rails 3.2.5 and compass-rails 1.0.1 and everything works fine. Have you installed `comapss-rails`, not just `compass`?

Comment: Unfortunately, installing `compass-rails` made no difference. Same error and behavior.

Comment: Could you put some code? I use compass in my sass files adding mixins and that all.

Comment: Is "compass watch" not working either? I am getting the same error because of a problem with my install.

Comment: @Cmorales — Nothing is working. Every Compass command gives me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be a bash script setting the full path, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

name=$1
cd /Users/Envs/dev/
compass watch $name
```

But this only helps to run compass and doesnt let you do anything else. A better solution would be to delete your local ruby 1.9.3 etc. and install [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/). Use rvm to install ruby 1.9.3 (or different version if you still get the error).  I recommend running sass/compass from its own rvm gemset for each project. Do something like this:

```
$ rvm gemset create myproject
$ rvm gemset use myproject
$ rvm gem install sass
$ rvm gem install compass
```

After installing everything you start compass with

```
$ rvm gemset use myproject
$ compass dosomething
```

Comment: The fix he describes is already implement in the latest Compass version (0.12.1). How would your second suggestion work differently than the already implemented fix? This bug is really slowing me down. Thanks so much.